# Why we have activity in android? instead of using view only?

Tags: android

I am learning Android recently, one puzzle I have is that about Activity and View, as I know each app contains one or multiple Activities, and each Activity has a View, my question is:

Why do we have Activity, instead of using View only, currently I don't see any advantage of this design?

Anyone can give me some explanations, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basis for designing the android framework like this is the **model-view-controller** pattern.

- The android views are the **View** part of the pattern
- The activity is the **Controller**
- The your database and logic for manipulating your data is the **Model**

The purpose of this pattern is to make reusable components. That's why the View is a separate concept: it is only used to visualize data, and shouldn't know anything about the logic of your application. That job is handled by the model and the activity (the controller, which is mostly used to update the view's state based on what's happening in the model and vice versa).

This is why you can easily use android's standard views in any application without changing anything about the view implementation itself. And if you design your own view subclasses to follow this pattern, it should be the same.

The least reusable part of the MVC pattern is usually the controller, and this is often the case with activities - they can be made in a reusable way as well, but more often than not they are the most application-specific part of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Because Activity is one of the main component of Android supported by delvik architecture.

Please go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)

Answer (score 0):

Activiy hold up and contains Layouts, wich contains **Views**. Activities let you manages and organize the differents interfaces of your application, for example: first Activity contains a List (you will use a ListView) and second Activity contains some details of an item of your list (TextView for some texts or ImageView for an image).

As you can see Views can be various and let you design your interface in the way you want.

I think you have to read [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) and [this too](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), in order to have more info about activity and [this one](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) for Layouts and View.

EDIT

I gave to you a brief example and some link, because i'm not english native speakers and i don't want to increase your confusion.

Answer (score -1):

You said, "each Activity has a View". I think you misunderstood what's a View.

In android, each activity may have one or more Views. Like TextView, ImageView, ListView, etc..

Apart from Views, Activity maintains its own Life cycles.

[image]

So, an Activity is something more than a UI.
For more [Activites|Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)